# Writing a vector into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

let's say i got `x=seq(0,1,0.2)` and `y=x[1:2]`.
How do I say that a given matrixes, e.g. `z=matrix(0,10,10)`, first 2 inputs in the first column should be the ones from y?. So I want to be y a part of z (if that makes sense).

I tried `z[[1:2],1]=y` but this doesn't work.

How do I do that neatly without any loops?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need the double brackets

```
z[1:2, 1] <- y
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Since the length of `y` is less than the number of rows of `z`, you can use

```
z[1:2] <- y
```

since values are assigned by columns from left to right